# Get/subtract current value from an input tag Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to dynamically update a sum of two fields in `angular` based on user input. At first it is linked to some data taken from the `database`. I managed to change the input and update the sum, but I somehow need to subtract what was before in the field in sum calculation. Now the sum adds also what was previously in the field and I don't want that behaviour.

`.html` file

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form>
        <input class = "textbox" type="text" name="Name" [ngModel]="user._30_geplant (change)="updateSum($any($event.target).value)">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form>  
        <input class = "textbox" type="text" name="Name" [ngModel]="user._30_buro (change)="updateSum($any($event.target).value)">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <p class = "delta" [ngModel]="delta30" ngDefaultControl>{{delta30}}</p>
</div>
```

In the `.ts` file

```
constructor() {
    this.delta30 = this.user._30_geplant + this.user._30_buro;
}

updateSum(sum: number) {
   this.delta30 = (+this.delta30) + (+sum);
}
```

What I have tried so far seemed not to work.

Comment: Because you use ngModel to bind the input values, you can use the same calculation as used in the constructor in updateSum then there is no need to know what the previous value was to subtract

Comment: just use two-binding way `[(ngModel)]` and in .html `{{+user._30_geplant+(+user._30_buro)}}` see how you need convert the string in a number using `+`variable. NOTE: when we split the two-binding it's usually use `<input [ngModel]="variable" (ngModelChange)="variable=$event;anotherFunction()">` -you forget equal the variables to the "input value"